# If the method doesn't change the parameter, why can't I pass it as const?

Tags: c++, constants

I'm a student who still doesn't quite get const parameters. I understand why this won't work:

```
#include <stddef.h>

struct Node {

    int value;
    Node* next;
};

Node* cons(const int value, const Node * next) {

    Node * tmp = new Node();
    tmp->value = value;
    tmp->next = next;

    return tmp;
}

int main () {

    const Node * k;
    k = cons(1, NULL);

    Node * p;

    p = cons(2, k);

}
```

This is because I am "casting away" the constness of k by giving p its address.

What I intended by marking the parameter "const" was to say that my method won't change the node directly. Where as if I were to pass in (Node * next), I would feel like there is no guarantee that my method is not dereferencing that pointer and messing up the node. Maybe this is foolish, since there is then no guarantee that later on the const Node I passed a pointer to won't get changed via the new pointer to it. It just seems strange that: in this method cons, all I am doing is pointing a new pointer at 'next' - I never touched next, just pointed - and yet that is enough to break the constness.

Maybe I have just underestimated the strength of the "const" promise.

Thanks!

Comment: What? What doesn't work? Why is 'k' const?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for something like "const Node const *next"

Comment: `const Node const *` doesn't make any sense, since both `const` modifiers apply to the `Node` part (not to the `*`). You either want `const Node * const` or `Node const * const` (both are equivalent).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue is that your `next` argument is of type `const Node *` (read: a pointer to a constant Node object), whereas the `Node::next` field is of type `Node *` (a pointer to a non-const Node object).

So when doing

```
tmp->next = next;
```

You try to make the compiler take a pointer to a const `Node` object and assign it to a pointer to a non-const `Node`. If this worked, it would be a simple way to circumvent constness, because suddenly people *could* modify the `next` argument simply by dereferencing `tmp->next`.

Comment: The OP knows that, he wants to know what else to do, because the parameter won't be changed in the function, so he wants to pass as const.

Comment: @Xeo: Maybe this wasn't apparent enough in my response: it doesn't matter if the function actually changes the argument. What matters is if the function *could* change the argument (that's why I emphasized the "could").

Comment: Yeah: the function could cast away the constness and then immediately mess with the node. Is there just no way to make a method that is mainly dealing in the re-assignment of pointers, which takes const parameters? Could I make the temporary node const, and then somehow cast away the constness when the method returns? Is that a thing? Or am I fretting over nothing and should really just be passing (Node * next) despite that my instincts say const?

Comment: @Ziggy: In essence, your `cons` function takes a `const Node *` but it returns a structure which contains a `Node *` - and both pointers reference the same object. So the function effectively internally casts away the constness, according to its signature. I'd personally just change the argument type to `Node *`.

Comment: You could add this last comment to the answer. The bigger problem (if it compiled) is not so much with `*(tmp->next)` (because it is a small function and you can easily see that it is not doing anything naughty) but with `*(p->next)` in the caller's code.

Comment: OK I think that with that comment this is the answer.

Answer (score 3):

> Maybe I have just underestimated the strength of the "const" promise.

So what is the promise that you made? The function takes a *copy* of a pointer to a `Node` and promises not to allow any modification of that `Node`. The promise is not about the pointer, that would be `Node * const` (and rather useless, since it is passed by value and the `const` at that level is removed from the signature), but about the pointee, the `Node`.

To provide a real life example, consider that a friend has offered to water your plants while you are on holidays, under the promise (usually implicit) that he will not *steal* anything from your house. Now you make a copy of the key and give it to your friend, who makes a copy of the key himself and gives it to a third party that never promised not to rob you. Do you consider that your friend broke his promise? How strong was his promise?

The code above has exactly the same pattern, `cons` promises that you can give it a copy of a pointer to a `Node` and that it won't allow it to be modified, but as soon as you enter the code, he copies that pointer to a different pointer that makes no promises whatsoever about the `Node`, and then hands the copy away to whoever might be interested.

Answer (score 2):

If `T` is any type, then there are two related *pointer* types, `T *` and `const T *`.

You obtain pointers in nature by taking the "address-of" some object of type `T`. The type of pointer depends on the constness of the object:

```
T x;
const T y;

T * p1       = &x; // OK, &x is T*
// T * p2    = &y; // Error!
const T * q1 = &y; // OK, &y is const T *
const T * q2 = &x; // also fine
```

So if we have a mutable object, a pointer to it is naturally a pointer-to-mutable. However, if we only have a constant object, then a pointer can only be a pointer-to-constant. Since we can always treat a mutable object as a constant one (just don't touch), a pointer-to-mutable can always be converted to a pointer-to-const, as in the case of `q2`.

This is what's happening to your `k`: It's a `const T *` (with `T = Node`), and we're assigning it the value of a `T *`, which is fine, since we just ignore the fact that we could have mutated `T` if we liked.

[In real life, we usually have constant *references* rather than flat-out constant objects, but you can treat those essentially as the same thing (since a reference is just an *alias* for an object and functionally identical to the object itself).]

Now you may be confusing all these `const`s with the constness of the object itself: Just as earlier we had `x` and `y`, one mutable and one constant, we can apply the same logic to the pointer type itself: Let us define `P = T *`, and `Q = const T *`. Then the above code, all our objects were *mutable* objects `P p1, p2; Q q1, q2;`. That is, we can always *change* any of the pointers to point somewhere else: `q2 = &z;`. No problem. That's what you're doing to `k` when you're reassigning it.

Of course we can also declare *constant* versions of these pointers: `const P p3 = &x; const Q q3 = &y;`. These *cannot* be reassigned (being constants, after all). If you spell this out in terms of `T`, as people usually do, it gets a bit loud:

```
T       * p3 const = &x;
const T * q3 const = &y;
```

I hope that didn't create more confusion than it resolved!

Comment: I often like to write `T const * const` instead of `const T * const` since the former nicely follows a "Type/Modifier" pattern. It also works nicely for more complicate stuff like `char const ** const` which you can read from right to left as "constant pointer to pointer to constant character".

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: Reading from right to left is the initiation rite, isn't it :-)

Comment: I won't upvote what I can't read -- what's going on? :-) Oh, what's that website that explains the spiral reading?

Answer (score 1):

> Maybe this is foolish, since there is then no guarantee that later on the const Node I passed a pointer to won't get changed via the new pointer to it. It just seems strange that: in this method cons, all I am doing is pointing a new pointer at 'next' - I never touched next, just pointed - and yet that is enough to break the constness.

It isn't simply that you pointed, it's that you pointed with a non-`const` pointer.  If you make `Node::entry` a `const Node*`, things should work.

Of course, that limits what you can do later when manipulating your list.

There are effectively two different forms of `const` in C++:  "honestly-truly `const`" and "`const` as far as you're concerned right now."  Most of the time you'll deal with the second kind, like in the example.  However, your program needs to work correctly with both forms of `const` to be `const` correct:

```
int main()
{
    const Node n = { 5, NULL };
    Node* p = cons(6, &n);
}
```

It's undefined behavior to cast away `const` on `n` (or on a pointer to `n`), and `cons` must respect that.  I should also mention that I believe part of your assumption is that you recognize that your function **could** modify the `const Node*`, but argue that since the troublesome assignment is the last line of the method the compiler should recognize that it **doesn't** actually do anything wrong.  I'm not aware of any rule in C++ that states "it is illegal to do X, unless of course you do it as the last line of a function."  The assignment is not allowed regardless of whether it comes first or last in the function.

You might be able to get the design you want and have `const` correctness as well.  For instance, you **are** allowed to overload `cons` to take either a `const Node*` or a `Node*` and build up lists of `const` or non-`const` elements accordingly.  If I knew more of what you want to do, I might have a better answer on how to get there.